# How faithful is the script of 2 Guns to the comic?

Tags: comic-adaptation, 2-guns

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2_Guns#Production), *2 Guns* is an adaptation of the comic series of the same name by Steven Grant. How true is the script to the comic series?

Answer (score 2):

One key difference: Both of the protagonists in the 2 Gun series are White.

Reference:
http://www.comicbookmovie.com/fansites/GraphicCity/news/?a=76645